# React: Handling mapped states

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, state

I'm very new to coding and trying to figure out an issue I have come across.
I am using axios to pull a json file and store it in a state. (I am also using Redux to populate the form)
Then I am using .map() to dissect the array and show one value from within each object in the array.

```
example json:
unit :
[
    { 
        designName : x, 
        quantity : 0, 
    },
    { 
        designName : y, 
        quantity : 0, 
    },
    { 
        designName : z, 
        quantity : 0, 
    }
]
```

I have then added an input to select the quantity of the value mapped and now I want to give that value back to the state, in order to send the entire modified json back to the API with Axios.
I feel like I'm close but I'm unsure what I need to do with the handleQuantity function.
Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import store from '../../redux_store'
import axios from 'axios';
import { Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

store.subscribe(() => {
})

class developmentSummary extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            prjName: store.getState()[0].developmentName,
            units: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://API')
            .then(
                res => {
                    console.log(res)
                    this.setState({
                        units: res.data.buildings
                    })
                    console.log(this.state.units.map(i => (
                        i.designName
                    )))
                }
            )
    } 
   handleQuantity() {
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="Text2">
                    {this.state.prjName}
                </div>
                <div className="Text2small">
                    Please select the quantity of buildings from the list below
                </div>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.units.map((object, i) => (
                        <div className="Card-center">
                            <Card key={i} style={{ width: "50%", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                                <Card.Body>{object.designName}</Card.Body>
                                <Card.Footer>
                                    <input
                                        className="Number-picker"
                                        type="number"
                                        placeholder="0"
                                        onChange={this.handleQuantity}
                                        
                                    />
                                </Card.Footer>
                            </Card>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the change `event`, `unit` object and the `index` to `handleQuantity` and then paste your changed unit as new object in between unchanged units.

Here is the code:

```
<input
  className="Number-picker"
  type="number"
  placeholder="0"
  onChange={(event) => this.handleQuantity(event, object, i)}
/>;
```

And the code for `handleQuantity`

```
handleQuantity = (event, unit, index) => {
  const inputedNumber = +event.target.value; // get your value from the event (+ converts string to number)
  const changedUnit = { ...unit, quantity: inputedNumber }; // create your changed unit

  // place your changedUnit right in between other unchanged elements
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    units: [
      ...prevState.units.slice(0, index),
      changedUnit,
      ...prevState.units.slice(index + 1),
    ],
  }));
}
```